# Disabling Auto-Layout in One View messes with screen

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, cgrectmake

I am trying to disable AutoLayout for one exact view called `conversationVC`.
As it is a chat and I got the code from a project which is not using Autolayout.

My idea was to use

```
self.view.removeConstraints(self.view.constraints)
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

to remove AutoLayouts constraints and add my own ones from `CGRectMake`
For some reason the screen gets messy.

This is my view hierarchy:

[image]

This is what the screen looks like using no code at all to remove AutoLayout:
[image]

**Now trying to remove and Autoresize all single Items in my View it looks like this:**

[image]

As you can see certain views become missing.
Any idea how to overcome this behavior?

*note: add button is in the correct position.*

**Edit: It is not a duplicate since it addresses the whole view and it's elements other than a single label. also i don't think Autoresizing is the problem, but something else**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn on/off auto layout for a single view controller in storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592239/how-to-turn-on-off-auto-layout-for-a-single-view-controller-in-storyboard)

Comment: Anbu what exactly do you mean by tableview code? my tableview functions like cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: sorry @JVS -- no need of code, show your type message size attribute in storyboard, if you did the copy paste on your view , it will happen, for testing purpose add the background color and check once

Comment: @JVS -- I agree is not a duplicate question

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik do you mean the size of the View containing the textfield to type a message? edit: Even with a background color it disappeared. seems to be off the view.

Comment: added the code for the individual view (frameMessageView) why do i have to add this for all views?

Comment: @JVS -- simple just delete your `show your type message` and add again once

Comment: Works! Thank you very much.